# VLC won't play HEVC files in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, vlc, hevc

I'm unable to play HEVC files in VLC 2.2.4. I use 14.04 LTS. I tried the following solution.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

It doesn't work. This is the error I'm getting.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc-plugin-libde265 : Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For `apt-cache policy libvlccore7` the output is

```
libvlccore7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2
  Version table:
     2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

For `sudo apt-get install -f libvlccore7` the output is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvlccore7 : Depends: vlc-data (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but 2.2.4-3ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1york1 is to be installed
```

I don't really understand this as I do have VLC 2.2.4.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libvlccore7` and `sudo apt-get install -f libvlccore7`?

Comment: Edited question to include output of the code you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the source code repository and software restricted by copyright legal issues, as seen in this image:

[image]

Then, run a package cache update with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After updating, search your plugin package by running:

```
sudo apt-cache search vlc-plugin-libde265
```

I suggest for you to install `ffmpeg`.

Comment: The source code repositories won't help.

Comment: it helped me in the case look like his case and by adding the repository i solved my probleme

Comment: But one cannot install binary packages from the source package repositories. How would they have helped?

Comment: i have the same problem and i solve it by this way , may be he should to search the correct repository for the vlc-plugin and add it , try to check to if there is broken packages on the system if you find you should fix it

Comment: I'm saying that the *restricted* repository may have solved you issue but I'd bet a month's wage that the *source code* repository is completely unrelated to the solution and purely incidental.

Comment: May be ubuntu admins changed the rules , i dont know i will try to search for him about other soulation

Comment: I'm not arguing about posting rules of AskUbuntu and didn't flag your post for anything. I'm doubting the veracity of your claims.

Comment: i understand thank you for sharing us the soulations ^_^